# How do I make a button make text show up in different activity?

Tags: android, button

How do I make it so when I press a button, text with the time and date shows up in a different activity? I would like it so you can see as many of these in "cards" on that activity with scrolling (see image one). Image two is the button to press.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the two Activities are simultaneously displayed: you can send a Broadcast when the Button is clicked. And the Activity with the cards needs a corresponding BroadcastReceiver

Comment: What are you trying to show on the second button exactly? Can you show code as well as screenshots?

Comment: Is it possible to display two activities?? Or your comment is misleading? @0X0nosugar

Comment: How about two Activities in split screen mode, @Xenolion?

Comment: Okay in Android 7 its possible, but can it work in the same app? @0X0nosugar

Comment: @Xenolion - I think I read somewhere (e.g. [here](https://www.androidauthority.com/use-same-app-both-split-screen-windows-android-7-0-nougat-715701/)) that it's even possible to open the same app twice if you don't take steps to inhibit it. (I suppose it would be in two processes, but go tell that to the users. It's like two tabs in your desktop browser, both showing pages of your favourite online store)

Comment: I think it would be helpful for us if we knew more of the specific situation. So far we only have two pictures, no code. So one can only guess...

Comment: Mmmmh yeah I have got it. Due to the nature of the question its impossible to guess...

Comment: I dont have any code, just ideas.

Comment: @Simon - then your question is way too broad. We're better at helping people with just the next step. Why don't you start with a hello world app and try to modify it to achieve your goal, and once you get stuck somewhere specific you can come back here

Answer (score 0):

- Create a database. (Check Room or SQLite)
- Add record with button
- When accessing the activity that has the ListView, load the records from the database.

I give you a simplified example on creating a database; however, there are a lot of tutorials out there. This one use Room which is a layer above SQLite.

Example:

**In app\build.gradle, add in dependencies section:**

```
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0'
```

**In your main activity, do:**

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db_stuff";
private ADatabase aDatabase;
```

(We will setup the abstract class ADatabase later)

**Setup the database:**

```
private void setupDatabase(){
    final File fileDb = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
    if (!fileDb.exists()){
        createDatabase();
        loadDatabase();
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "Database already exists"));
    }
}

private void createDatabase(){
    RoomDatabase.Builder<ADatabase> builder;
    builder = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
            ADatabase.class,
            DATABASE_NAME);
    aDatabase = builder.fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();
}

 private void loadDatabase(){
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            Stuff stuff = new Stuff();
            stuff.setId("1");
            stuff.setName("Candle");
            aDatabase.daoAccess().insertStuff(stuff);

            stuff= new Stuff();
            stuff.setId("2");
            stuff.setName("Chair");                
            aDatabase.daoAccess().insertStuff(stuff);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

**Create the abstract class I describe above:**

```
@Database (entities = {Stuff.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class ADatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract IDaoAccessStuff daoAccess();
}
```

**Create the DAO interface:**

```
@Dao
public interface IDaoAccessStuff {

    @Insert
    void insertStuff (Stuff stuff);

    @Update
    void updateStuff (Stuff stuff);

    @Delete
    void deleteStuff (Stuff stuff);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Stuff WHERE id = :id")
    Exercises fetchStuffById (int id);

    @Insert
    void insertALotOfStuff (List<Stuff> stuff);

    @Query("DELETE FROM Stuff")
    void emptyTable();
}
```

**Create the Model of your table:**

```
@Entity
public class Stuff {
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;

    private String name;

    public Stuff(){}

    @NonNull
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(@NonNull String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I created the SQLite database, but iv'e never done it, still working on it

Comment: I showed you how can you do it without SQLite and use Room instead (which is a layer on top of SQLite).

I leave the rest for you to figure out.

Comment: Each time you press the button, save to the database then refresh the ListView with the information in the database.